# How to set the file name based on a parameter in the sink?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to set the file name based on parameter in the sink of a mapping data flow?
The expression builder thinks this is fine, and the parameter is drag-and-drop:able in the interface, but when running the data flow in a pipeline (that passes a pipeline parameter into the data flow parameter $OutFileName) it fails with "unsupported syntax in expression. Details:at Sink"

I have tried different variations of the expression, like "{$OutFileName}" and with the toString() function and so on...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression for the sink file name must contain single quotes, meaning that you have to have them in the pipeline expression/parameter you're passing - or you must have the box for "Expression" un-checked in the parameter tab of the data flow activity in the pipeline as it will then add the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Is $OutFileName a data flow param of type String? If so, all you should have to do from the pipeline is set it like this in activity's parameter setting: (choose "data flow expression") 'myfile.txt'

[image]

Comment: Yes it is, but I want to set the parameter for the data flow activity in the pipeline based on an expression containing a pipeline parameter. I guess I have to choose "pipeline expression" in the UI of your picture then to be able to use it. But still, I get the unsupported syntax failure when it's running the data flow

Comment: Yes, use "pipeline expression". Would you mind pasting your expression here?

Comment: For example @replace(item().name, '.ORC', '.PARQUET'). The item is from a get metadata activity. I have exactly the same expression for a copy data activity within the same foreach container, where it works fine. I guess the unspported syntax comes from within the sink component of the data flow.