# How to remove extra files when sinking CSV files to Azure Data Lake Gen2 with Azure Data Factory data flow?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have done data flow tutorial. Sink currently created 4 files to Azure Data Lake Gen2.
I suppose this is related to HDFS file system.

Is it possible to save without success, committed, started files?

What is best practice? Should they be removed after saving to data lake gen2?
Are then needed in further data processing?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-data-flow

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options available.

1. You can mention the output filename in Sink transformation settings.

   - Select [**Output to single file**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#sink-settings) from the dropdown of file name option and give the output file name.
   - You could also parameterize the output file name as required. Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61123171/how-to-set-the-file-name-based-on-a-parameter-in-the-sink) thread.

     [image]
2. You can add [delete activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity) after the data flow activity in the pipeline and delete the files from the folder.

[image]